Index and nullity of a short closed geodesic
Let $g$ be a reasonably smooth Riemannian metric on the n-dimensional sphere $S^n$. Call a closed geodesic $\gamma$ in $(S^n, g)$ short if, for every diffeomorphism $S^n \to S^n$, the image of at least one circle is at least as long as $\gamma$. Are there any known lower bounds for the Morse index and nullity -- or some combination thereof -- of at least one short closed geodesic in $(S^n, g)$? (E.g., some short closed geodesic must have index at least $n - 1$, index and nullity that sum to at least $f(n)$ for some function $f$, or such.) Does assuming that $g$ is bumpy help?

Do you consider only the metric $g$ on $S^n$? And by circle, do you mean closed geodesic?

Perhaps I should have defined a circle: A curve diffeomorphic to $S^1$ obtained by intersecting a 2-plane in $R^{n+1}$ with $S^n$.

If I'm understanding your question correctly @SebastianGoette: I mean that the image of at least one circle (defined above) is at least as long as $\gamma$, with the length of the image measured with respect to $g$.
